# compare 2 directories and copy differences in a 3rd directory

Tags: linux, rsync, directory, diff

Running ubuntu 12.04, I want to compare 2 directories, say folder1/ and folder2/ and copy any files that are different to folder3/. There are also nested files, so matching subdirectories should be copied as well

Is there a single command that would help me? I can get the full list of changed files running:

```
rsync -rcnC --out-format="%f" folder1/ folder2/
```

But rsync doesn't seem to have the ability to "export" these files on a different target directory. Can I pipe the list to cp or some other program, so that the files are copied, while the directories are created as well? For example, I tried

```
rsync -rcnC --out-format="%f" folder1/ folder2/ | xargs cp -t folder3/
```

but that wouldn't preserve directories as well, it would simply copy all files inside folder3/

Comment: I'd probably use some combination of `diff -qr` and `awk` to build the list, then `rsync`...

Comment: how would I use rsync with the list?

Comment: I'd either run a for-loop or use the `rsync --include-from=FILE` option.

Comment: (don't be lazy...) But the [rsync solution](http://serverfault.com/a/508272/13325) below is elegant.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use --compare-dest.

From the man page:

> --compare-dest=DIR - 
>       This option instructs rsync to use DIR on the destination machine as an additional hierarchy to compare destination files against doing transfers (if the files are missing in the destination directory). If a file is found in DIR that is identical to the sender's file, the file will NOT be transferred to the destination directory. This is useful for creating a sparse backup of just files that have changed from an earlier backup.

first check your syntax with --dry-run

```
rsync -aHxv --progress --dry-run --compare-dest=folder2/ folder1/ folder3/
```

Then once you're satisfied with the output:

```
rsync -aHxv --progress  --compare-dest=folder2/ folder1/ folder3/
```

this [link](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2006-June/015827.html) has a good explanation of --compare-dest scope.

Comment: Thanks for this, I hadn't understood the man page explanation of this parameter. For anyone interested, I did it with `rsync -rcC --compare-dest=folder2/ folder1/ folder3/`

Comment: quick note for OsX users. I have `rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31` on my local and rsync doesn't understand `~/` paths for `--compare-dest` param.

Comment: For me, `--compare-dest` required an absolute path.

Comment: Didn't work for me with either author's or OP's options. I.e. it outputs `fonts/Makefile.in` file, which is identical in both `folder2` and `folder1` dirs.

Comment: @Hi-Angel My first attempt was similar, realized I missed the trailing `/` forward slashes. After adding them it worked as described.

Answer (score 3):

This little script should work:

```
folder1="firsts_folder/"
folder2="second_folder/"
folder3="target_folder"
for x in `rsync -rcnC --out-format="%n"  $folder1 $folder2`
    do
        if [ -d "$folder1/$x" ]; then
            mkdir -p "$folder3/$x"
        else
            cp -frv $folder1/$x $folder3/$x
        fi
done
```

But I also think that parsing output of diff -qr would be a better solution because it gives you path and name for each file consistently.

**EDIT**

This would be one command, your command slightly modified. But it will create `folder1` under the `folder3`. And it does not work with full paths but also the script above does not work with full paths.

```
rsync -rcnC --out-format="\"%f\"" folder1/ folder2/ | xargs cp --parents -rfvt folder3/
```

I used `\"` in `rsync` to make it work with files and directories containing blanks. Tested on Ubuntu 10.04. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for this, I had hoped that a single command would exist though

Answer (score 2):

```
rsync -rcnC --out-format="%f" . ../folder2/ |xargs cp --parents -rt ../folder3/
```

That's the simplest form I could come up with, if you're willing to first descend into `folder1` before issuing the command.

This is the **slower** option, but I believe it meets your requirements, and it could be executed using non-relative directory names:

```
rsync -rcnC --out-format="%n" folder1/ folder2/ |grep -vP "/$" |xargs -I{} rsync -R folder1/./{} folder3/
```

I left your original `rsync` command alone, because you said it was giving you the correct file list (and my test files are obviously different than yours, so I couldn't say for certain that I'd be getting the correct file list if I messed with it).

The `grep` is there to remove directory names from the output of `rsync`.

The output of `grep` is then piped to another `rsync` using `xargs`.  In the param `folder1/./{}` the extra `./` is used to tell rsync to create the relative directories starting with `./{}`, ignoring `folder1/`.  In other words, it avoids creating `folder3/folder1/`.

I was only able to test this on CentOS 6.4, but AFAIK it should work the same in Ubuntu 12.04.

**EDIT:**  I should note that *smithian*'s answer is undoubtedly better, but I wanted to take a stab at doing it with your original `rsync` command in tact since it was giving you the desired output.