# Compare 2 Directories and Move Differences to a Third directory

Tags: linux, rsync, directory, diff

Running Ubuntu 20.04 and want to compare two directories called 1 and 2 and move differences to a separate directory called 3, ideally conserving the subdirectories.

I am able to get almost the desired effect using:

`rsync -aHxv --progress  --compare-dest="$PWD"/2 1/ 3/`

except that it copies the files instead of moving them.

I've also tried other answers from a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/506005/compare-2-directories-and-copy-differences-in-a-3rd-directory), but the goal there is to copy, not move, and it seems that using mv doesn't conserve the subdirectories.